# Matrix all possible combinations of two rows with opposite sign

Tags: performance, r, matrix, addition

I have a matrix of positive and negative integers. I want to add together all
possible combination of any two rows that have opposite signs in a specific column (column "a" in my example below), such that the addition gives a zero in this column.

The combined rows rows are put in `newmat` and `newmat[,"a"]` has only zeros.

A problem is that my solution becomes prohibitively slow for larger matrices (>500 rows).

```
##initialize matrix
nof.rows <- 100
mat <- cbind(matrix(ncol=40, nrow=nof.rows, sample(40*nof.rows)),
         matrix(ncol=6, nrow=nof.rows, c(1,2,-1,3, -2, -3),
                dimnames=list(seq_len(nof.rows),c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"))))

newmat <- matrix(ncol=ncol(mat), nrow=0)

##column which will contain nothing but zeroes
col <- "a"

for (i in seq_len(nrow(mat))){
  curr.row <- mat[i,]
  curr.col <- mat[,col]
  opposite.sign.indices <- vector()
  if(curr.row[col] > 0)
    opposite.sign.indices <- which(curr.col<0)
  else
    opposite.sign.indices <- which(curr.col>0)
  opposite.sign.indices <- setdiff(opposite.sign.indices, seq_len(i))
  for (j in opposite.sign.indices){
      opposite.sign.row <- mat[j,]
      newrow <- (abs(opposite.sign.row[col]) * curr.row
                 + (abs(curr.row[col])*opposite.sign.row))
      newmat <- rbind(newmat, newrow)
    }
}

newmat <- unique(newmat)
```

Any ideas of how I could speed up the process? Thanks in advance -H-

Comment: is there a deeper goal, or do you truly just want columns of 0s?  If so, you are probably much better off just counting

Comment: Well, the obvious thing is to allocated storage for `newmat` first. At the moment you allocate 0 rows. If you don't know exactly how many rows `newmat` will need, allocate a lot of rows, fill it in and in the loop keep check of how many rows have been filled. When you have filled it up, allocate a lot more rows and carry on filling. That way you only do the copy/extend for a few iterations. At the moment you are growing `newdat` at each iteration of the inner loop, which is woefully inefficient.

Comment: @Ricardo Saporta In my new matrix I want one specific column to contain just zeroes. Any two rows r1 and r2 with opposite signs in column 'a' should be combined to a new row in the new matrix such that newrow=|r2['a']|*r1 + |r1['c']|*r2. This way, my column 'a' gets balanced.

Comment: @Gavin Simpson: Thanks! Your suggestion speeds it up at about factor 10!

Comment: @user1981275 Good. Let this be a lesson: **never** grow an object within a `for` loop in R, at least not at each iteration. Allocating storage, even if you don't know exactly how much is needed, will not slow the loop down with all the copying that takes place when you grow an object (other than a list).

Comment: I just tried it using a list: It works just as fast and I do not have to allocate during the process. Then I just have to convert the list into a matrix newmat=t(sapply(mylist), unlist)). This is the most convenient solution in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

This is much faster:

```
##initialize matrix
nof.rows <- 100
mat <- cbind(matrix(ncol=40, nrow=nof.rows, sample(40*nof.rows)),
         matrix(ncol=6, nrow=nof.rows, c(1,2,-1,3, -2, -3),
                dimnames=list(seq_len(nof.rows),c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"))))
col="a"

pos.row.idx <- which(mat[,col]>0)
neg.row.idx <- which(mat[,col]<0)
newmat <- unique(t(apply(expand.grid(pos.row.idx, neg.row.idx), 1, function(x){
  abs(mat[x[2],col]) * mat[x[1],] + abs(mat[x[1],col]) * mat[x[2],]
})))
```